# Como excluir um dado de uma ou mais tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: fazer]Eu tenho um id que aparece em varias tabelas mas, eu preciso excluir ele na pagina principal e que exclua em todas as outras tabelas também. 
ex :

```
DELETE FROM admissao_dominio.*,  admissao.*,  bancarios.*,  boas_vindas.*,  documentacao.*,  exame_admissional.*,  gestao.*,  interno.*,  parametros_captacao.*,  propostas_contratacoes.*,  sede.*,  suporte_interno.*,  tipo.*,  usuario_atv.*,  vencimentos.*,  vias_documentos_funcionarios
WHERE EMAIL = '{$_GET['id']}'";
```

tá errado mas é tipo alguma coisa desse tipo que eu preciso.

Comment: Essas tabelas possuem relacionamentos entre si? Se elas se relacionam, você pode deletar usando inner join.

Comment: sim elas estão todas ligadas pelo id_usuário, ou por alguma outra chamada, tipo é um cadastro de usuário e os dados aparecem em diferentes lugares, mas quando eu clicar em excluir eu preciso excluir de todas as tabelas

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233479/6580921), é bem provável que resolva o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra deletar mais de uma tabela, você precisa *juntar* todas elas.

```
DELETE admissao_dominio,  admissao,  bancarios/*,  boas_vindas,  documentacao,  exame_admissional,  gestao, interno,  parametros_captacao,  propostas_contratacoes,  sede,  suporte_interno,  tipo,  usuario_atv,  vencimentos, vias_documentos_funcionarios */
FROM admissao_dominio
JOIN admissao ON admissao.ID = admissao_dominio.ADIMISSAO_ID
JOIT bancarios ON bancarios.ADMISSAO_ID = admissao.ID
/* join das demais tabelas */
WHERE EMAIL = '{$_GET['id']}'";
```

Tenta assim, fazendo *join* entre todas as tabelas, isso deve excluir corretamente!